# Installscript : How to close explorer windows without restart of explorer.exe process?

Tags: windows, installshield, explorer, installscript

is there anyway to close all the explorer windows without restart of explorer.exe process?

Context :- During un-installation of an installshield based installer, i had to delete a dll which is used to show right click context menu for the files. During un-installation i had to delete the dll. Unfortunately it is getting locked by explorer.exe.

Is there anyway just close explorer windows without restart of explorer.exe process?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could call FindWindow and use SendMessage to close the explorer windows but the explorer.exe process will still be running and you'll still have a file lock.

Windows Installer can delete locked files on reboot.  If you don't want the reboot, you'll have to kill and restart explorer.

I know of no other patterns here.

[WM_SYSCOMMAND message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

FindWindow Example from [InstallScript Language Reference](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield25helplib/Subsystems/LangRef/helplibrary/LangrefFindWindow_example.htm):

```cpp
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*\
*
* InstallShield Example Script
*
* Demonstrates the FindWindow and SendMessage functions.
*
* This script launches Windows Notepad and then calls
* FindWindow to locate the Notepad window.  Next, it calls
* SendMessage to maximize the window;  after a three-second
* delay, it calls SendMessage again to minimize the
* window.   When the script ends, Windows NotePad remains
* open but minimized.  Note that the parameters passed to
* SendMessage are Windows system messages whose values
* are defined as constants in this script.
*
* Note: Before running this script, set the preprocessor
*       constant NOTEPAD so that it references the fully-
*       qualified name of the Windows Notepad executable.
*
\*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
 
#define NOTEPAD "C:\\Windows\\Notepad.exe"
 
// Include Ifx.h for built-in InstallScript function prototypes.
#include "Ifx.h"
 
export prototype ExFn_FindWindow(HWND);
 
function ExFn_FindWindow(hMSI)
    NUMBER nMsg, nwParam, nlParam;
    HWND nHwnd;
begin
 
    // Do not display the setup's background window.
    Disable (BACKGROUND);
 
    // Open the Windows Notepad.
    if (LaunchApp (NOTEPAD, "") < 0 ) then
        MessageBox ("Unable to launch Notepad.", SEVERE);
        abort;
    endif;
 
    // Wait three seconds so we can view the window before
    // it's maximized.
    Delay (3);
 
    // Retrieve the handle of the Notepad window.  The first
    // parameter is the window class.  A null string in the
    // second parameter specifies the topmost Notepad window.
    nHwnd = FindWindow ("NotePAD", "");
 
    if (nHwnd = NULL) then
        MessageBox ("Unable to find the Notepad window.", SEVERE);
    else
        // Send system command to maximize the window.
        SendMessage (nHwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0);
 
        // Wait three seconds so we can view the window
        // before it's minimized.
        Delay (3);
 
        // Send system command to minimize the window.
        SendMessage (nHwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MINIMIZE, nlParam);
    endif;
 
end;
```

Comment: Oh cool. I was able to delete the dll file manually just after closing all the explorer windows without restart of explorer.exe. I think i can try closing explorer windows in installscript. Would be really helpful to me if you can throw some install script which finds all explorer windows and closes them.

Comment: I don't "throw install script" together for people. Answer updated to give you some pointers. Hope it works...

Comment: Thanks for updating the comment. The example looks for NOTEPAD window. My aim is to find explorer window. I tried this to find handle for the explorer window, unfortunately it is not returning the handle. FindWindow ("ExploreWClass","");  The class name i have provided is for Explorer window. Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: There's a program called Spy++ shipped with various versions of Visual Studio and Microsoft SDK's.  It'll show you a list of all window handles and what their class names and captions are.

Answer (score 0):

After googling so much and lot of trails, i could come up with following c++ program which just closes explorer windows without restart of explorer.exe process.

Here i am using EnumWindows and iterating through all the windows and closes just explorer windows alone based on class name of the window.

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using  namespace std;

wofstream myfile;

BOOL CALLBACK enumWindowsProc(
  __in  HWND hWnd,
  __in  LPARAM lParam
) {
 

  int length = 255;

  TCHAR* buffer,*buffer1;
  buffer = new TCHAR[ length + 1 ];
  buffer1 = new TCHAR[ length + 1 ];
  memset( buffer, 0, ( length + 1 ) * sizeof( TCHAR ) );
  memset( buffer1, 0, ( length + 1 ) * sizeof( TCHAR ) );

  DWORD pid;
  DWORD dwThreadID = ::GetWindowThreadProcessId( hWnd, &pid);

  ::GetWindowText(hWnd,buffer,length +1);
  wstring windowTitle = wstring( buffer );
  delete[] buffer;
    
  //cout << windowTitle.c_str();
  ::GetClassName(hWnd,buffer1,length +1);
  wstring windowClass = wstring( buffer1 );
  delete[] buffer1;
  
  if(windowClass.compare(L"CabinetWClass") == 0 || windowClass.compare(L"ExploreWClass") == 0)
  {
      //::PostMessage(hWnd, WM_ENDSESSION, MAKEWORD(true,1), ENDSESSION_CLOSEAPP);
      //::PostMessage(hWnd, 0x5B4, 0, 0);
      PostMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
  }
  
  myfile << windowTitle.c_str();
  myfile << L"|" ;
  myfile << pid ;
  myfile << L"|" ;
  myfile << windowClass.c_str() ;
  myfile << L"\n" ;

  return TRUE;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                       HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                       LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                       int       nCmdShow)
{
    myfile.open ("processes.txt");
    BOOL enumeratingWindowsSucceeded = ::EnumWindows( enumWindowsProc, NULL );
    cin.get();
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```